# I wonder if the jetpack navigation comonent are good enough for the situation like that the main fragment hold a MapView with lots of markers on it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

When using heavy view (like a map with lot of markers on it),navigate to other fragment and switch back to the map fragment will probably make view become blocked.The map need to callback at lifecycle methodes,and mapview and markers drawn agin,so very time popup to map fragment this will rebuilt again ,is there any good way to handle that with navigation component?